# Cloning repository within certain period

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, clone

I am working on a research and I would like to investigate git, Mercurial, and svn repositories. However, some of the repositories that I am looking for is huge and it is hard to inspect the complete history. So, I would like to know if there is any way where I can clone a repository between 2 dates or from 2009 - 2013 for example?

I would like to know how to do so for git, mercurial, and svn if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: So far as I know there's no such facility for clone, but you can restrict log output by date with `--since` and `--after`.  "huge" tends to be relative, are you sure just cloning them won't take less time than trying to not just clone them?

Comment: @jthill I will try to see if restricting log output will work in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mercurial there are no such things as partial clones limited to a certain time frame.

If you can actually clone the repo, then limiting log output to a certain time span is easy (also check `hg help dates`):

`hg log -d"31/1/2013 to 24/12/2014"`

And in svn similarly:

`svn log -r {2013-01-31}:{2013-12-31}`

If you really need and want and must make partial clones, you can use with mercurial the convert extension. But that usually is quite slow when used over network; thus a complete clone likely is faster.